# jquery error from variable selector name. Can someone show me the proper way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

If it isn't clear what I'm trying to do here, I need to select a dynamically generated class from the document and bind a click function to it. Here is the code. Selecting the variable class, if it exists is posing the problem.

```
if( item.current == '2' )
                    {

                         playBeep = true;

                        htmlStr += '<tr class="current-alert curaler' + incrementer.toString() + '">';

                        var selectorString = 'curaler' + incrementer.toString();


                        $( ('.' + selectorString) ).bind( 'click' , function() 
                            {

                            alert('hi');



                            });

                    } 
                else if ( item.current == '1')
                    {
                     htmlStr += '<tr class="current">';
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        htmlStr += '<tr>';
                    }

                htmlStr += '        <td class="first">' + item.percent + '%</td>';
                htmlStr += '        <td class="second ' + ( ( item.current == '2' ) ? 'sym' + incrementer.toString() : '' ) + ' ">' + item.symbol + '</td>';

                if(item.symbol != 'CASH'){
                    htmlStr += '        <td class="third">@</td>';
                } else {
                    htmlStr += '        <td class="third"> </td>';
                }

                htmlStr += '        <td class="fourth">' + item.purchasedAt + '</td>';
                htmlStr += '        <td class="stockName">' + item.fullName + '</td>';
                htmlStr += '    </tr>';
            });
            htmlStr += '    </table>';
        } else {
            htmlStr += "<i>100% Cash</i>";
        }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, but of course you haven't shown what's in the "selectorString" variable.

Comment: It should be working the way you are sketching it, can you show us the whole (real not pseudo) code you are using?

Comment: selectorString = "curaler0" an incrementing class assignment in the html

Comment: think its because the html isn't in the page yet?

Comment: @mprototype, it indeed seems you're calling `bind()` before the elements matching `selectorString` are actually added to the page. You might want to add `htmlStr` to the document first, or use `delegate()` instead of `bind()`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the element you're trying to target is not part of the dom yet.

Try using [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.' + selectorString).live ('click' , function() { ... } );
```

or, for jquery 1.7 onwards use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.' + selectorString).on('click' , function() { ... } );
```

Alternatively, just make sure you run `bind()` after the element has been inserted.

If you're generating multiple elements, it might be easier to just make sure they all have a common class and use assign your click event to that class using `live()` or `on()`.

Comment: funny thing, I just got to sit back down on this and even with the html on the page I'm getting an error on the selector saying its null, which isn't the case.... any ideas?

Comment: @mprototype Can you post the updated code and full error message?

Comment: TypeError: $(".curaler0") is null --> I'm just running this in the console in firebug just doing a css replace

Comment: @mprototype That sounds like jQuery wasn't properly loaded. What happens when your run `$().jquery` in your firebug console?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is correct as you have it, however if the element does not exist yet when this is executed, it might now be found.

Here is an alternative method which would pick up any element with a partial class match:

```
$("[class^='curaler']").on('click', function(){
    //do stuff here
});
```

Done the way above, you don't have to put this in your conditional, it can just be in your

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//  put it here
}};
```

EDIT: Based o your last update:

```
$( ('.' + selectorString) ).
```

should be

```
$('.' + selectorString).
```

or

```
var myselector= '.' + selectorString;
$(myselector).on('click',function(){
  alert(  $(this).text());//sample to alert the text of the clicked element
});
```

NOTE: If you are using pre 1.7.1 version you can use 'delegate' instead of "on" with slightly different syntax.

EDIT2: Discussion on the difference between .delegate, .live, and .bind here:  http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery

but with version 1.7 forwards you can use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(( '.' + selectorString) ).bind( 'click' , function(){});
```

Is the proper way !

Comment: however the paren's in the $( ) seems to be the area not working.

Comment: what do you mean by paren's in $() ?! My line of code does exactly that what you required ? And whoever downvoted that could explain me the reason ?! this line simply fits the requirements !!

Answer (score -1):

What you have there is correct for the selector assuming the html element is in place. You can use `bind`, but I prefer `click`.

```
$('.' + selectorString).click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

More info on the jQuery site about click: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with using ".bind()" like that. In jQuery 1.7 you'd use ".on()" instead however.

Comment: Isn't `.bind('click'` just a shorthand for `.click(`?

Comment: You are all correct. I like .click because it simplifies the syntax for just a click. Also, I posted a full example as the question doesn't have syntactically correct code.

Comment: But since jQuery 1.7 I would recommend to use .on()

Comment: preference doesn't matter, click, bind, both work. The selector is not working. Is it because I didn't inject the html in the page yet?

Comment: You can't select something that hasn't been injected ! It's like touching a baby when it's in its mothers womb !